# How to parse an index query in Neo4j?

Tags: parsing, lucene, neo4j

I'm querying neo4j's auto index several times trying to retrieve nodes by the property *ID*. It works well most of the time, but if my query contains a *lucene special character* (+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : ) I get a ParseException.

I tried to parse the query string with the following code (as suggested [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t86124.html)):

```
String escapeChars ="[\\\\+\\-\\!\\(\\)\\:\\^\\]\\{\\}\\~\\*\\?]";
```

`String escaped = userInput.replaceAll(escapeChars, "\\\\$0");`

As a result, the index query returns null.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there better way of escaping those characters?

Edit:

I also tried using Lucene's `QueryParser.escape(query)` method with no luck.

Comment: Can you provide the query that is giving you trouble?  And also, if the exception provides any further information, that could be helpful.

Comment: Use parameters instead of literal values for your query, and put double quotes around your value in the lucene query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier to put it in quotes if you can (and double quotes need a `\\` in front of them, in Cypher, anyway).

```
id:"my_id_with*123y47123&"
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/bpxvzv